# convert equation from polar coordinate to cartesian coordinate

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I have the following equation
$$r= \frac{A}{\log\left[B\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2N}\right)\right]}$$

For using an optimization program, I would like to have this equation in cartesian coordinate system.
Is it possible to have x,y equations for the above equation.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: For B > 0  and N > 0 ?

Comment: Thank you Taussig for the edit and the link to the tutorial.

Comment: Yes Narasimham, for B>0 and N>0.

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly possible as:

$$ Exp {\dfrac { A }{     \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} }   } = B \, tan \,[ \dfrac { \tan^{-1} \frac{y}{x} }  {2 N }  ]    $$

Comment: Is it possible to get this into a y=function(x) form.

Comment: Implicit means it is not possible to express y explicitly as f(x)